# PostgreSQL query between a date range but only between specific hours

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, time

I am trying to create a query that will only query rows that are between a date range and only reside within a certain times of day.

I'm able to query this okay as long as the time range is within the same day, but this isn't guaranteed in my application (the time range could fall across the day boundary). For example:

```
SELECT * FROM data
WHERE data.utc BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2022-01-01'
AND data.utc::time BETWEEN time '16:00:00' AND time '22:00:00'
```

Is it possible to support both cases just using SQL?

The case where I may need to query between:
'16:00:00' --> '22:00:00' of the same day AND
'22:00:00' --> '04:00:00' across the day boundary

I can do something in the application to work out the WHERE conditions but was wondering if there is a cleaner SQL method to do this.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you not just combine your between checks to do date and time?  In between use:  '2021-01-01 16:00:00'  (not sure with postgresql, but others I have worked with you can do this)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can use:

```
where ( (:start_time <= :end_time and data.utc::time between :start_time and :end_time) or
        (:start_time > :end_time and data.utc::time not between :start_time and :end_time)
      )
```

Note that `between` includes the endpoints and `not between` does not.  I don't know if that is what you really want.  I actually recommend using `>`/`>=` to be unambiguous about your intentions.